# Extending classes without overriding anything: Bad practice?

Tags: java

I'm taking over an old project. Now I have some classes in the flavor of *own util class overriding a util class of external library*. E.g.:

```
public final class StringUtilsXXX extends org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils {
}
```

These classes are not overriding any methods of the extended class at all (and never will be in the future). I find it confusing, that most calls on the own implementation are just delegating to the super class. Is this bad practice?

Comment: "most calls on the own implementation are just delegating.." what are the other calls doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is bad practice. The argument for why is that it tightly couples your own classes to a third party library. I'm sure the reason your predecessor did this, is so that if he needed to some day replace commons-lang, he would only have to change one piece of the code. He probably did this because of frustration from upgrading from lang2 to lang3.

The way he should have done this, would have been to create a StringUtil interface, and write different implementations of this (you could have a StringUtil which was implemented using lang2, one that used lang3 and even maybe a fallback implementation that was implemented from scratch. (if you needed some string handling not provided by either, or if you needed to compile some versions with an older Java version, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Normally not needed if you are not overriding anything or adding any data or method member in subclass. However, for future placeholder, this may be used.

Answer (score 0):

It will not hurt for now. But using (has a) StringUtils should be preferred over extending it, if no additional behavior is provided.

If there is an interface available for StringUtils and you are pointing your implementation (extending class instance using it) then it might still make some sense from maintainability point of view (that again depends on how you are instantiating it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider it as a bad practice necessarily. There are cases that you may not want to rely on the API of an external library, and you might want to build a wrapper layer between the client (your) code and the external library. The reason doing this would be that **you have control of the API** of the wrapper contrary to the API of the external library.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what he really did, from the pattern standpoint, is a decorator. I don't know anything about this particular library (because I'm a .net dev) and does it expose interfaces that he should implement instead but I would rephrase the question to:
Is it fine to create decorators on 3rd party libraries or should we make adapters instead.

As far as I see it, adapters are the right answer. But there is something more that puzzles me here: shouldn't we always try as hard as we can not to break contract when upgrading our project we give away to others? Did "they" have to introduce new namespace? 
If they did, should we blame our colleges for hacking code to maintain project despite someone else's doubtful ideas/solutions?

Comment: I don't see how this is anything other than plain old inheritance. Decorator pattern usually implies that the derived class is hanging on to an instance of the base class, which is pointless here since StringUtils is just a collection of static methods.

Answer (score -1):

No.. This is a bad practice. Suppose tomorrow org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils changes something (removes a method. Though it is unlikely, it can still happen with other classes especially with custom classes), imagine the impact it would have on your code. You are actually tightly coupling your methods with org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.

Comment: That would happen even if the OP is to use `StringUtils` directly without extending it in some other class.

Comment: @R.J - I totally agree. Its just that I think finding that an error exists in  StringUtils.someMethod() is easier than finding an error in MyClass.someMethod()

Comment: If you are planning to extend only StringUtils, then this would work because it is highly unlikely that it will change. If you are planning to use this approach on custom classes, then(inspite of the downvotes :P) I still think its not the right approach.